# wrapping third party function inside document.write()

Tags: javascript, document.write

I am placing the below inside document.write(). But its a third party function & the first param is the key and second is the value. I will be passing the value , so it cannot be inside document.write() . So how do I write it?

```
document.write('populateData("Number",shownum);');
```

Comment: Are you looking for a way to print the outcome of call to populateData method?

Comment: No I'm trying to pass in the value from my end into the thirs party function as a second argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking how to concatenate strings in Javascript, it would look like this, using the `+` operator:

```
document.write('populateData("Number", "' + shownum + '");');
```

Comment: populateData() is a third party function in the tag that they have given. because I can't put it directly inside the DOM I'm using document.write(). However putting a third party function with two args inside document.write(). The second param is the data which is passed from my end to the third party server through this function. shownum contains some value( eg shownum= abc) . So when I concatenate using the above , it says in console that abc is not defined,

Comment: What data type is `shownum`? If it's a string, you have to properly quote it, obviously. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for your help SpikeX. The above worked. I appreciate it. also I've a question. Is there any alternative to using document.write()? Since I can't put the third party tag in DOM I've used this. but in general its not a good thing to use document.write. I tried using createElement('script'); but is that the right way too? I've updated the code above. And totally thanks for ur help.